# Where is ISafeRunnable?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, include

I have downloaded a code that was written on the Eclipse platform, and I want to compile it, but one of the `jar` files that I include, uses a class called `ISafeRunnable`, and the class's canonical name is:
`org.eclipse.core.runtime.ISafeRunnable`. But no matter how many jar files starting with `org.eclipse.core.runtime` I add to my build path, none of them contains `ISafeRunnable`!!! Help Please!!!!

Comment: Makes you want to help. [Here it is, OP](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse.equinox/common/3.5.0/org/eclipse/core/runtime/ISafeRunnable.java)

Comment: Found [this](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.eclipse.core.runtime.ISafeRunnable)?

Comment: @CodeCaster: I tried that before asking the question!! It's not in there!! But thanks anyway...

Comment: Hey guys!! So, there is this View in Eclipse, called: Plug-in Dependencies... You can bring it up by Going to Window>Show View>Other>Plug-in Dependencies...
What this view does is it can focus on any dependency (jar) and tell you what is that jar dependent on itself... And you can import the entire plug-in with it's dependencies as a Java Project to your workspace... Came pretty handy to me... So... Just thought about sharing the experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would it help if you import `org.eclipse.equinox.common` as well? Check [this thread](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t59401.html?start=15), for example:

> The ISafeRunnable interface is located in the equinox plugin
>   (org.eclipse.equinox.common). If you add the SWT library to your
>   project, it should be added to the build path automatically. You can
>   do this by right-clicking your project, choosing Build Path/Add
>   Libraries... and then selecting the SWT Library. Afterwards, your
>   project should contain a new folder, having the same icon as the JRE
>   folder, and containing a couple of jars, including org.eclipse.swt...
>   and org.eclipse.equinox.common.

Comment: Thanks... I added the `org.eclipse.equinox.common` and tada!!! The class is there, but the second part of your answer doesn't work for me. When I open Buildpath/Add Library, there is no SWT option there!!! My Eclipse is Eclipse 3.7.1 J2EE... I always add swt by adding the jar file manuallyL org.eclipse.swt.cocoa/win32....

Answer (score 0):

It is in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` jar library. See this [link](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/jarClasses/540) for the list of interfaces included in the library. Make sure you are using the right [platform (3.7)](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/ISafeRunnable.html) version

Comment: Of what Eclipse version? It got factored out to `equinox.common` a long time ago.

Comment: Eclipse 3.7: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FISafeRunnable.html

Comment: You provide a link to its Javadoc. Its package name is not disputed, but the ID of the OSGi bundle it resides in. From your link I wasn't able to deduce the bundle ID. Did you see my link in the comments?

Comment: Can't see the link :(. On the right hand side of the page it says 'Release 3.7' I doubt they did not update that when generating the docs

Comment: The link is under the words "Here it is, OP", second comment under the question. Your page indeed says "Release 3.7", but where does it name the bundle where that class resides?

Comment: My experience shows that jarfinder results are a little off sometimes, including this very instance... JarFinder said it's in org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.1.0.jar, but it's not!!!!

Comment: Oh I see, mmm are you by any chance using Maven?

Comment: @MostafaZeinali JarFinder is right as far as its claim that the class is included in `org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.1.0.jar` It's just a quite irrelevant piece of information.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but that jar file is not shipped with eclipse anymore!! Or is it??!! 
@GETah: No I'm not using Maven...

Comment: @MostafaZeinali It is shipped with Eclipse 3.1. You would, however, spend quite some time digging it up in the Eclipse archives.